# dplyr: efficient way of selecting n rows of a column post arrange on different column

Tags: r, sorting, select, dplyr

Is there any better way of doing this? Especially selecting 10 rows of column `hp` without using two functions separately like this. I have checked using `top_n(10)`, but it does not work after using `arrange()`.

```
mtcars %>% arrange(desc(.[[3]])) %>% select(hp) %>% head(10)
#    hp
#1  205
#2  215
#3  230
#4  175
#5  175
#6  245
#7  264
#8  245
#9  150
#10 150
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a <- 
  mtcars %>% 
    top_n(10, disp) %>% 
    arrange(desc(disp)) %>% 
    select(hp)

b <- mtcars %>% arrange(desc(.[[3]])) %>% select(hp) %>% head(10)


identical(a, b)
#[1] TRUE
```

You can also do arrange first, but that will be slower

```
a <- 
  mtcars %>% 
    arrange(desc(disp)) %>% 
    top_n(10, disp) %>% # same as head(10) since already sorted
    select(hp)

b <- mtcars %>% arrange(desc(.[[3]])) %>% select(hp) %>% head(10)


identical(a, b)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks, But performing it without two functions is not feasible. Good to know!